# JavaFX How to simulate ScrollEvent

Tags: listview, javafx, scroll, javafx-8

I need a custom implementation of scroll up/down of a ListView, for this I want to use

```
listView.fireEvent(new ScrollEvent(...))
```

The problem is that the constructor of the scrollEvent is to complex (http://goo.gl/Dl0cxy), I just need to move x pixeles up or down. How could I use an easy implementation just like

```
listView.fireEvent(new CustomScrollEvent(x,y))
```

where x,y are the pixeles I need to move from the current scroll position ? I really dont know all the info asked in the ScrollEvent constructor.

Comment: check this out http://stackoverflow.com/questions/26537548/javafx-listview-with-touch-events-for-scrolling-up-and-down

Answer (score 0):

You can use [Flowless](https://github.com/TomasMikula/Flowless) instead of ListView. There, you can use the methods [scrollX(dx)](http://www.fxmisc.org/flowless/javadoc/org/fxmisc/flowless/VirtualFlow.html#scrollX-double-) and [scrollY(dy)](http://www.fxmisc.org/flowless/javadoc/org/fxmisc/flowless/VirtualFlow.html#scrollY-double-) to scroll the content.